# Android - LinearLayout in ScrollView in Relativelayout

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have a little problem with layouts.
I have made RelativeLayout in which I put two LinearLayouts (1 and 2) and between them ScrollView with LinearLayout. Next I set that ScrollView to be placed under linearLayout2 and above linearLayout1. But LinearLayout inside that ScrollView isn't set as it's parent.

Here's the code, maybe I've made a mistake:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
        android:padding="6dip"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/lin1"
        android:layout_weight="1">

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/lin3" 
        android:layout_height="60dip">          

</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:layout_below="@id/lin1"
android:layout_above="@id/lin3" android:id="@+id/ScrollView">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"                      
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/lin2" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

    <Button android:text="@string/button1" 
        android:id="@+id/button1" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="280dip" 
        android:layout_height="60dip">
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="@string/button2"
        android:id="@+id/button2" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="280dip" 
        android:layout_height="60dip">
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="@string/button3" 
        android:id="@+id/button3" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="280dip" 
        android:layout_height="60dip">
    </Button>

    <Button android:text="@string/button4"
        android:id="@+id/button4" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:layout_width="280dip" 
        android:layout_height="60dip">
    </Button>


</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any ideas, why LinearLayout inside of ScrollView is bigger than the ScrollView?

EDIT:
So far I've noticed that LinearLayout inside of ScrollView moves outside when I set layout_gravity="center_vertical". It looks like setting center refers to main layout (RelativeLayout).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I've made it.
All I had to do is setting LinearLayout that is inside of ScrollView to

```
layout_width="wrap_content"
layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
```

The ScrollView to

```
layout_width="fill_parent"
layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
layout_height="wrap_content"
```

And at the end I've put that ScrollView into new LinearLayout with parameters as following:

```
layout_width="fill_parent" 
layout_height="fill_parent" 
gravity="center_vertical" 
orientation="vertical"
```

So the ScrollView and it's child Layout are setting buttons center horizontaly and the outer LinearLayout is setting them center verticaly. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the `layout_width` of `lin2` to `wrap_content` instead of `fill_parent`.

Comment: The problem isn't the width, but height, where lin2's height is bigger than it's parent - ScrollView

Answer (score 0):

try this code i think this is the best sollution

```
  <HorizontalScrollView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" >
   </HorizontalScrollView>
```

---