# how to fit a large layout within a single screen with multiple listviews

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

[image]i am working with a project in which what i have to do that there are two lists and the layout is very large you can say that it is just double to a normal layout. i have to add scroll view to show whole layout but the problem is that there can't be a list within a scroll view if i do so then there is ambiguity to compiler that which is scrolling if it is list or scroll view  . Now what should i do help me thanks in advance ...

I am also attaching an image which is half of my layout....

[image]

Comment: I think the approach of whole layout scrolling is not good (for a good UX). Try weighted linear layout, wrapped by a relative layout (fill_parent - height,weight)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667589/android-linearlayout-in-scrollview-in-relativelayout
check this if it is useful then accept it or vote me

Comment: Your are adding List View inside scroll View?

Comment: actually no,i just want such kind of functioning

Comment: If i understand correctly you need to divide entire layout into two half in equal proportion right or some other proportions?

Comment: You can show only a preview of the lists, for example only show 3 items of each list and add a button to show the full content.
In that case you can use a scrollview and display the list items using a LinearLayout

Comment: u r ryt bt i would like to make it more clear ...its a long layout in whih there are two lists as shown in figure bt the prob is for making a efficient layout i want to gve that lists proper area and for that i have to put all that content within a scroll view bt its not possible to put a list within a scroll so what should i do...

Comment: For example you can Populate progratically a LinearLayout with items like a listView, its not hard to do

Answer (score 1):

From your query i designed one sample XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffff" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#ffffeabc" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

In above you will have Scroll View for larger height Views and also you have equal proportion of list View. Thing you have to concentrate is on `android:layout_weight` , you should check how to play using **Weight** attributes

**Edit :**

Okay one thing you can do is that , We can use **Header footer concept of List View** - *make ImageView and 2nd List View  as footer of 1st List View so that ImageView and 2nd ListView will always comes Below 1st List View*..

[For Header Footer concept check this Link](https://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=add+footer+in+listview+android&oq=footer+in+List+View+andri&aq=1lmK&aqi=g-lK1g-lmK2g-blK2&aql=&gs_l=hp.3.1.0i13i30j0i13i5i30l2j0i8i13i30l2.614.11590.1.13566.40.31.7.2.2.0.312.5146.0j28j2j1.31.0...0.0.y4xk-lB-BIA&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e60f6c2a0919fb7f&biw=1440&bih=812).

Comment: thanxxx buddy ...bt the prob is that if ill do this i will have to compromise with the appearance of the layout ....will have to make lits look small to fit into screen ...is der any other way???

Comment: actually prob is that the for my 1st list i need to show at end at much it contains items so this may lead to exceed from screen size so need to apply a scrollview on a list view.which is blocking my list.and at the end of my 1st list i need to show some buttons after again another list with a fixed size..please suggest any solution..

Comment: You need to show the entire list?Or only scroll that 3 items like the images?

Comment: @Rahulkapil Edited my answer , check it

Comment: Rahulkapil.. I'm facing the same problem as yours... do you have any final solution on it? if so please post it on here.